# Can't remove directory by node number

Tags: linux, shell

I have an empty directory I can't rename or remove, even if I try to remove it by node number.  Below shows the commands I've tried.  The only anomaly I see is that the shell's filename completion appends a slash to the filename (shown in the rmdir command). Any suggestions are welcome. The filesystem is ext4.

```
$ ls
'Every Breath You Take: The Classics'

$ ls -bl
ls: 'Every Breath You Take: The Classics': No such file or directory
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 Nov 28  2014 Every\ Breath\ You\ Take:\ The\ Classics

$ rmdir "Every Breath You Take: The Classics"/
rmdir: failed to remove 'Every Breath You Take: The Classics/': No such file or directory

$ stat "Every Breath You Take: The Classics"
stat: cannot stat 'Every Breath You Take: The Classics': No such file or directory

$ stat "Every Breath You Take: The Classics"/
  File: Every Breath You Take: The Classics/
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 16384  directory
Device: 37h/55d Inode: 7323        Links: 1
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/ user)   Gid: ( 1000/ user)
Access: 2020-05-27 21:18:31.130341500 -0700
Modify: 2014-11-28 23:14:32.000000000 -0800
Change: 2019-02-02 13:27:19.052670600 -0800
 Birth: -

$ find . -inum 7323 -exec rmdir {} \;
rmdir: failed to remove './Every Breath You Take: The Classics': No such file or directory
find: ‘./Every Breath You Take: The Classics’: No such file or directory
```

Here is the output from several responders suggestions:

```
$ ls | hexdump -C
00000000  45 76 65 72 79 20 42 72  65 61 74 68 20 59 6f 75  |Every Breath You|
00000010  20 54 61 6b 65 3a 20 54  68 65 20 43 6c 61 73 73  | Take: The Class|
00000020  69 63 73 0a                                       |ics.|
00000024

$ rmdir *Every*
rmdir: failed to remove 'Every Breath You Take: The Classics': No such file or directory

$ rm -i -r Every*
rm: descend into directory 'Every Breath You Take: The Classics'? y
rm: cannot remove 'Every Breath You Take: The Classics': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What filesystem is it (btrfs/ext4/ntfs...)?

Comment: That `size: 0 blocks: 0 links: 1` is also abnormal for a directory. Sounds like a corrupted FS. I would go for a `fsck`.

Comment: The `rmdir` you run through `find` does pretty much exactly the same as doing `rmdir Every<tab>` on the command line with tab-completion. Both read the directory listing and pass the _name_ to `rmdir`. The fact that the other uses the inode number as search condition and the other uses the name doesn't change this. The underlying `rmdir()` call also takes a name. And if it gives ENOENT for a directory that is listed anyway, it does indicate that your filesystem is somewhat weird (or just broken somehow).

Comment: Let `rm` keep the internal name for you: `rm -i -r Every*Breath*You*Take*`

Comment: It's possible that the dir name contains additional non-printable/special characters. Try `ls | hexdump -C` to check this.

Comment: @GreenJalapeno You better edit your question to add new information there; longer text and code is very hard to read in the comments. However, from the current impression I tend to agree with Stéphane; looks like a corrupt directory.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! It took over a year, but I found a solution.

It turns out the directory in question was on a Networked Attached Storage device. So I used `ssh` to connect directly to the device, and when I examined the directory it appeared normally.  I was able to remove the contents and then the directory itself with standard `rm` and `rmdir` commands.

It's still a mystery why the directory wouldn't respond normal commands from the desktop.

Answer (score -2):

It almost looks like the ticks (') are part of the file name:

```
$ ls
'Every Breath You Take: The Classics'
```

You can't simply say:

```
$ rm 'Every Breath You Take: The Classics'
```

as the shell will eat the ticks.

Instead, try:

```
$ rmdir  *Every*
```

Comment: No, this is how GNU `ls` outputs filenames that it considers special (in this case, it contains spaces).